# Onclick button, state doesn't change

Tags: react-native

I'm having some troubles understanding the code.
Basically if I do this:

`<Text onPress={() => console.log('123')} >123</Text>`
,
and I click on the text, it logs me 123 each click.

But I'm doing a dialer app. Basically having a component Tile (representing a single number, also with secondary option (but that will be dealt with later)).
So as I'm including my (currently only single one) Tile in App.js, I want onPress event to call function that changes state of currently dialed number. So if user clicks 3 times on '1', I want the final string to be 111.
The thing is, I can see that the `handleNumber()` function is called once after running code and never again after clicking on the number, therefore never changing state, not logging anything.

**App.js Tile implementation:**

```
const [getNumber, setNumber] = useState();

  const handleNumber = (newChar) => {
    console.log(newChar);

    setNumber(newChar);
  }

<Tile onPress={() => handleNumber('1')} style={styles.tile} firstChar={'1'} secondChar={'✉'}/>
```

**Tile.js**:

```
const Tile = (props) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress()}> 
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.mainChar}>{props.firstChar}</Text>
                {props.secondChar ? <Text style={styles.secondChar}>{props.secondChar}</Text> : null}
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

**One more thing:**
As you can see in App.js::handleNumber(),
the implementation is currently wrong, because the final number will always be just the new single number, instead of appending it to the end of string.
But if I wanted to do smth like `setNumber(getNumber + newChar)`, it would give **Maximum update depth exceeded** error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing here is the way that you're passing the `onPress` prop to `TouchableOpacity`. See, you're **calling** the `props.onPress` function instead of just passing it to the component, which causes the function to be executed when the component renders (or rerenders).

You should be fine just by using `<TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>` and then `setNumber(getNumber + newChar)` will be fine as well.

As a side note, you could initialize your App.js state with the `'1'` string that you wish to be your initial value (`const [getNumber, setNumber] = useState('1')`), and then the Tile component can receive `getNumber` directly.